# what's the difference between kernel-header and kernel-devel

Tags: kernel, package-management, drivers, compiling

It seems kernel-devel will include header files and Makefiles.

So, kernel-header will only include header files without Makefiles?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are asking about CentOS. These packages can differ in other distributions.

Using `yum info` on those packages can give you a better explanation of what will provide you each package

This is the description for kernel-headers:

> Kernel-headers includes the C header files that specify the interface
>   between the Linux kernel and userspace libraries and programs.  The
>   header files define structures and constants that are needed for
>   building most standard programs and are also needed for rebuilding the
>   glibc package.

And this one is for kernel-devel:

> This package provides kernel headers and makefiles sufficient to build
>   modules against the kernel package.

Also, if you run `repoquery --list kernel-devel` you will see that it provides many header files not included by `kernel-headers`.

Comment: so, basically, we only need to install kernel-devel it covered everything?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. At CentOS, `kernel-headers` is not a dependency for `kernel-devel`. If you want both packages, you should install both.