# Having trouble installing TP-Link AC1300 in Redhat 7.9

Tags: rhel, drivers, kernel-modules, dkms, linux-headers

I am having trouble installing the driver for TP-Link AC1300 dongle in Red Hat.
I followed [this](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/208022) procedure for Ubuntu and it ultimately worked.
Have been trying to follow the same steps in Red Hat, to no avail.

1. Not sure how does one figure out what is the driver to install on Linux. The official site does not mention Linux support in the [driver page](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t3u/).
2. Following the tracks on google, I must assume it's realtek driver. Possibly [this](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu), perhaps [this](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au).
3. Tried the procedure I understand needs to be done:

   - cloning source code
   - adding symbolic link with dkms
   - install module using dkms

I can't get passed the 3rd bullet - install module with dkms.
Tried (using (this source code)[2](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t3u/)) `sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 4.2.2`
Get

```
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 cannot be found at /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/build or /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/source.
Please install the linux-headers-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.
```

There is one `install.sh` in the source code folder. Running it gives

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/build M=/home/qa_user/avraham/rtl8812au  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

If I try looking at what is at `/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/build`, I figure out it is a link, pointing to `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64`.
Trying again dkms install this time with --kernelsourcedir to the link above, like:
`sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 4.2.2 --kernelsourcedir /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64`
Gives

```
Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8812au/4.2.2/build/make.log for more information.
```

Looking at the log gives

```
DKMS make.log for 8812au-4.2.2 for kernel 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 (x86_64)
Wed Dec  8 16:19:11 EST 2021
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/8812au/4.2.2/build  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

which is the error I got at the beginning, meaning... I am stuck.

---

**Update (1):**

Followed @GracefulRestart suggestion. Tried installing the kernel headers for my linux kernel version.

**My linux kernel version (hostnamectl output): `Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64`**

Ran `sudo yum install -y kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64.rpm`.
Got message

```
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.GncnUX: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
    package kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64 (which is newer than kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64) is already installed
    file /usr/include/linux/version.h from install of kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64
```

I then removed kernel version 49.

Currently I have only what seems to be the proper kernel header:
`rpm -qa kernel`
Returns `kernel-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64` only.

As pointed by `@Natolio`, I should have ran `rpm -qa kernel-headers`.
Done, and the result is `kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64`.

---

**Update (2)**:

Went to /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 and tried running `make` there.
Got

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

---

**Update (3)**:

Running `lsusb` I figured out that I was trying (I did not know how to determine the matching driver !) the wrong driver source code. I have the dongle connected to the computer, and lsusb shows `TP-Link Archer T3U [\[Realtek RTL8812BU\]][5]`.
But following both the source code instructions to install or the procedure I was using originally with `dkms` - the result is the same.

---

How do I find solace here ?

Comment: Those errors seem to indicate that you have not installed the kernel headers for your currently running kernel.  Make sure that the `kernel-headers` package is installed and the same version as your running kernel.

Comment: @GracefulRestart: post updated, thanks.

Comment: Minor formatting comment: error messages are generally better formatted as code, because they have a specific format, and are easier to read if they are in that format.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: fix applied, thanks !

Comment: From your Update (1) it is unclear if you actually got the kernel-headers installed. The warning message stated that you had a newer version than what you were trying to install already installed at that it caused a conflict. Then you uninstalled the version of the kernel that you had the kernel-headers for (49). Did you then install the kernel-headers for the kernel that you were running? `rpm -qa kernel` will show you the versions of the kernel that you have installed, not the kernel-headers. Confirm that you have the correct version of kernel-headers installed. Run `rpm -qa kernel-headers`.

Comment: @Natolio: oops, good catch. `Update (1)` section updated. Thanks. It shows the matching version of the kernel header is installed.

Comment: In reference to `Update (2)` what is the goal of running `make` in `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64`? What happens when you run `make` in the directory where you clone [this](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu)? I would give the "Simple Usage" section of that a try first and see if you can `insmod` the driver. Then move on and see if you can get dkms working.

Comment: Obvious comment, but if you have the dongle working on Ubuntu, then you can reference that installation to figure out the driver to be used. Because Ubuntu should load the driver module for the dongle when it is use. (It would almost certainly be a module.)

Comment: Redhat : The package for building kernel modules is `kernel-devel` : `# yum install kernel kernel-devel` . ....... ( The Redhat "kernel-headers" is the user  space headers, see /usr/include/ ).

Comment: @KnudLarsen: Excellent. `sudo dkms install -m [...] -v [...]` now does build (or tries to) the source. Problem now is that no build in no source I experimented with completes without erros (mainly undeclared definitions). Will try some more. By the way, [on the topic you shed light on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586108/433212) - for my own reference.

Comment: [Interesting read](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi). To be completed sometime soon.

Comment: Followed README.md instructions (ultimately to run install-script.sh). Problem is still the [source](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702) does not compile. Could it be that node of the versions I tried are supported in kernel 3.10 (mine) ? The only source that explicitly states support is RTL8812AU, but since `lsusb` with the dongle connected shows RTL8812BU, I have been trying the latter only.